# Laravel 5 Missing route doesn't throw Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having an issue my missing routes behaviour. If I try a random URL no exception is thrown I get an

> Undefined variable: errors

instead of the 404 page that I have created. The thing is that if I try to access an object that doesn't exist in database from a valid existing route, the 404 error is thrown and the page is rendered like it should.

I have a layout for my error pages that includes a topbar and within that bar there is a modal form that I include in the master layout(the undefined error comes from that modal apparently):

**mastererror.blade.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <!-- Load CSS -->
    @include('assets.css')
    <!--------------> 
    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!----------------->

 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- Load Navbar -->
 @include('elements.html.navbartop')
 <!----------------->
 <div class="pusher">

    <div id="content" class="ui main container" style="margin: 70px 0px 50px  0px">
        <!-- Load Content -->
        @yield('content')
        <!------------------>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Load Footer -->
 @include('elements.html.footer')
 <!----------------->
 <!-- Load JavaScript -->
 @include('assets.js')
 <!--------------------->

 <!-- Load login Modal -->
 @include('elements.html.partials.login-modal')
 <!---------------------->

 </body>
 </html>
```

**404.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout.mastererror')

@section('title', 'Not Found.')

@section('content')

<div style="margin-top: 30px">
    <img class="ui medium image centered" src="{{asset('images/notfound.png')}}">
    <h1 class="ui header centered">404 Not Found.</h1>
    @if($exception->getMessage() !== '')
        <h2 class="ui header centered">{{ $exception->getMessage() }}.</h2>
    @else
        <h2 class="ui header centered">The resource is missing.</h2>
    @endif
    <h3 class="ui header centered"><a href="{{ route('index') }}">Home</a>   </h3>
</div>

@endsection
```

**login-modal.blade.php:**

```
<div class="ui small modal" id="loginModal">
    <i class="circular close icon inverted"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Login
    </div>

    <div class="ui active dimmer" id="loader" style="display: none">
        <div class="ui text loader">Loading</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="eight wide column centered">
                {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'auth.login', 'method' => 'post','id'=>'formLogin','class' => 'ui large form')) !!}
                <div class="field {!! $errors->has('username') ? 'error' : '' !!}">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="user icon"></i>
                        {!! Form::text('username','',['name'=>'username','id'=>'username','class' => 'pd','placeholder'=>'Pseudo']) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! $errors->first('username', '<span class="ui text" id="" style="color: #bf4d4b">:message</span>') !!}
                </div>
                <div class="field {!! $errors->has('password') ? 'error' : '' !!}">
                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <i class="lock icon"></i>
                        {!! Form::password('password',['name'=>'password','id'=>'password','class' => '','placeholder'=>'Mot de passe']) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="ui text" id="" style="color: #bf4d4b">:message</span>') !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::submit('Login',['id'=>'loginButton','class'=>'ui fluid large teal submit button']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
                <div class="ui message">
                    <p>Mot de passe oublié? {{ link_to_route('password.forgot','Réinitialiser',null,null) }}</p>
                    <p>Pas encore membre? {{ link_to_route('auth.register','s\'Enregistrer',null,null) }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now I added this route to catch any invalid routes:

```
Route::any('{catchall}', function($page){
        abort(404,"the page '$page' doesnt exist");
    })->where('catchall', '(.*)');
```

Answer (score 1):

The magic `$errors` variable is not generated when an error is thrown (discussed in more detail here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11457).

You'll need to do an `isset($errors)` on any templates you include that reference `$errors`

```
<div class="field {!! isset($errors) ? ( $errors->has('username') ? 'error' : '' ) : '' !!}">
```

Comment: Why is it that when an exception is thrown from a controller action, then there's no problem?

Comment: Because when you throw an exception in a controller it's going through the route middleware (specifically `ShareErrorsFromSession`). An exception like a 404 happens at a higher level and bypasses this.

Comment: @user3813360 Not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: well I have special characters on the 404 page and they aren't displaying correctly.. something's wrong with how that is generated

Comment: Do you have an example of the problem characters? Can't see any special characters in your original 404 template, and I'm not having any problems using accented letters on a 404 template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109578/discussion-between-matt-mcdonald-and-user3813360).